# Rearranging a linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm trying to solve the following problem

> Write a method split that rearranges the elements of a list so that all of the negative values appear before all of the non-negatives. 
>       For example, suppose a variable list stores the following sequence of values:

```
[8, 7, -4, 19, 0, 43, -8, -7, 2]
```

> The call of list.split(); should rearrange the list to put the negatives first. One possible arrangement would be the following:

```
[-4, -8, -7, 8, 7, 19, 0, 43, 2]
```

> But it matters only that the negatives appear before the non-negatives. 
>       So this is only one possible solution. Another legal solution would be to rearrange the values this way:

```
[-7, -8, -4, 2, 43, 0, 19, 7, 8]
```

> You are not allowed to swap data fields or to create any new nodes to solve this problem; 
>       you must rearrange the list by rearranging the links of the list. 
>       You also may not use auxiliary structures like arrays, ArrayLists, stacks, queues, etc, to solve this problem.

I'm really clueless as how to solve this problem. One approach which I'm thinking of is to identify nodes with negative data and add it to the head, but I'm unable to figure out how to code this approach. Here is my list class.

```
public class LinkedList {

// The Linked List's Node structure
   static class Node {
    private Node next;
    private int data;

    Node(int data) {
        this.data = data;
        next = null;
    }

    public int getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setNext(Node next) {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public void setData(int data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public Node getNext() {
        return next;
    }

}

private Node head;
private int size;

public void setHead(Node head) {
    this.head = head;
}

public int getSize() {
    return size;
}

public Node getHead() {
    return head;
}

public LinkedList() {
    head = null;
    size = 0;
}
}
```

Any hints/suggestion for tackling this problem?

As suggested by @nishu I have come up with the following solution. It works.

```
public Node delete(int data) {

    Node del = null;
    Node tmp = head;
    if (head.getData() == data) {
        Node tmp2 = head;
        Node nxt = tmp.getNext();
        tmp2.setNext(null);
        this.setHead(nxt);
        del = tmp2;
    } else if (isLast(data)) {
        while (true) {
            if (tmp.getNext().getNext() == null) {
                del = tmp.getNext();
                tmp.setNext(null);
                break;
            }
            tmp = tmp.getNext();
        }
    } else {
        while (tmp != null && tmp.getNext() != null) {
            if (tmp.getNext().getData() == data) {
                Node prev = tmp;
                del = tmp.getNext();
                Node nextOfToBeDeleted = tmp.getNext().getNext();
                prev.setNext(nextOfToBeDeleted);
                break;
            }
            tmp = tmp.getNext();
        }
    }
    return del;
}

public void addToFront(Node node) {
    node.setNext(head);
    this.setHead(node);
}

public void split() {

    Node tmp = head;
    Node del = null;
    while (tmp != null) {
        if (tmp.getData() < 0) {
            Node nxt = tmp.getNext();
            del = delete(tmp.getData());
            addToFront(del);
            while (tmp != nxt) {
                tmp = tmp.getNext();
            }
        } else {
            tmp = tmp.getNext();
        }

    }
}

public boolean isLast(int data) {
    boolean last = false;
    Node tmp = head;
    while (true) {
        if (tmp.getData() == data && tmp.getNext() != null) {
            last = false;
            break;
        } else if (tmp.getNext() == null && tmp.getData() == data) {
            last = true;
            break;
        }
        tmp = tmp.getNext();
    }
    return last;
}
```

Comment: You already have a reasonable idea, what difficulties are you facing with its implementation?

Comment: To add to the head, you put your current `head` in a temp var, add the new `head`, then set that new `head`'s `next` to the temp var.

Comment: By the way, your class does not correctly implement the `getSize()` function (which, BTW, should actually be named just `size()`). Also, you really ought to make the list class generic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the procedure to go further :

1. create methods : insert and delete.
    insert - it will insert data at the beginning.
    delete - it will search for the value passed and delete the first occurrence of item in   the list and returns the node that was deleted.
2. Start traversing the linked list. Whenever you find a negative node, delete it from existing linked list and call insert method on the node returned by delete function.

Comment: Your suggestion worked. I have updated the question with my implementation,

Comment: Also have a look over the implementation by AJMansfield. It is a clean way to do with this approach.

Answer (score 1):

Add a new interface to your node type:

```
static Node<T> implements Iterable<Node<T>> {
    private Node<T> next;
    private T data;

    public T getData() {return data;}
    public void setData(int data) {this.data = data;}

    public Node getNext() {return next;}
    public void setNext(Node<T> next) {this.next = next;}
}
```

The `NodeIterator` can then be

```
NodeIterator<E extends Node<T>, L extends LinkedList<T>> implements Iterator<E>{
    E last, current; L parent;
    public NodeIterator(E node, L parent){this.current = node; this.parent = parent;}
    @Override public boolean hasNext(){return current.getNext() != null}
    @Override public E next(){last = current; current = current.getNext(); return last;}
    @Override public void remove(){last.setNext(current = current.getNext()); parent.size--;}
}
```

Now that you have this, you can write the method for moving the list:

```
public class LinkedList<E> {

    private Node<E> head;
    private int size;

    public void insertAtHead(Node<E> node){
        node.setNext(head);
        head=node;
        size++;
    }

    public void split(Predicate<E> condition){
        Iterator<Node<E>> it = nodeIterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){
            Node<E> node = it.next();
            if(condition.test(node.getData())){
                it.remove();
                insertAtHead(node);
            }
        }
    }

    public Iterator<Node<E>> nodeIterator() {
        return new NodeIterator<Node<E>, LinkedList<E>>(parent, head);
    }
}
```

Invoke like this:

```
LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();
 // [... add stuff to list ...]
list.split((Integer i) -> i < 0);
```

EDIT: fixed the code so it will correctly update the list's size when the iterator's remove function is called. (Still works only with nodes that are contained in one list, though. If two list instances incorporate the same nodes, and one of their shared nodes is removed, only one will have its size updated.)

Comment: BTW, in case you don't recognize the syntax, I am using a lambda expression in the last code block (introduced in Java 8).

Comment: I also use diamond operators `<>`, which are only in Java 7 or later.

Comment: This looks a clean way to do it. What is this Predicate class that you used?

Comment: @nisu its in the `java.util.function` package; its a functional interface for something that takes one parameter of type `E` and returns a `boolean`.

Comment: @nishu I used the predicate class as a way to allow the list to be split up based on other attributes, rather than just the required 'negative' split. (In particular, I used it so the class could remain generic, instead of having to create a specialized class that could only handle `int`s.)

Answer (score 0):

For those who stumble across this looking for help with their Practice-IT question that is identical, I did the same problem in Practice-It and this is what passed all the tests for me:

```
public void split() {
  ListNode temp = front;
  for (int i = 0; i < this.size; i++) {
    if (temp.data < 0) {
      this.add(0, temp.data);
      this.remove(i + 1);
    }
    temp = temp.next;
  }
}
```

The idea is that we create our "temp" variable pointing to the front of our `linkedlist`, our for loop helps us iterate sequentially through all of the index locations within our `linkedlist`. our "if" conditions test whether the integer is negative, and if it is, then we want to add this number to the front of the list first, THEN remove it from where we found it. this order is important because if we remove first, we lose it, unless we save it into a variable first, but this approach is simpler. our call on the add() method tells it to add the value we are currently pointing at, to index 0, aka the front of our `linkedlist`. once we do this, we are suddenly pointing at the value prior to what we were pointing at, because we increased the size of the list by one by have not incremented our for-loop variables value yet, so when we call the `remove()` method, the index we pass to it must be 1 greater than what our for-loop variable I is currently set to, so our index is `i + 1`. we must move our temp variable to the next node by setting temp equal to `temp.next`, and we must do this outside of our for loop because we do this whether or not the value we are pointing at is negative. our for-loop test cannot be equal to the size of the `linkedlist` because of indexes beginning at 0, so our test is set to whether our I is less than the size of our `linkedlist`. this was the most straight forward approach I could think of utilizing the built in methods of the `LinkedIntList` class provided by Practice-It. not sure if that is where you encountered the problem but if it is not, I have faith that you will be able to apply the strategy according to what you are working with.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).